# Renaming doesn't work for column names starting with two dots

Tags: r, dplyr, readxl

I updated my `tidyverse` and my `read_excel()` function (from `readxl`) has also changed. Columns without titles are are now called `..1`, `..2` and so on, when they used to be called `X__1`, `X__2`.

I'm trying to `rename()` these columns starting with two dots, but I'm getting an error message.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:3,
             ..1 = 4:6)

df <- df %>% 
  rename(b = ..1)
```

Throws the error:

```
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

I get the same error if I use backticks around the name: `` rename(b = `..1`) ``.

Comment: Just FYI, I changed the last sentence because those are called backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`..1` is a reserved word in R.  See `help("reserved")` and `help("..1")`.  Try quoting it:

```
df %>% rename(b = "..1")
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     1     4
2     2     5
3     3     6
```

Comment: Not able to test but can one also use `backtick.. 1backtick`?!

Answer (score 2):

The [`janitor` package](https://github.com/sfirke/janitor) has a very handy function `clean_names` for tasks like this. In this case, it replaces any `..` that come from `readxl` with `x`. I added another `..` column to show how the replacement works.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(a = 1:3,
             ..1 = 4:6,
             ..5 = 10:12)

df %>% 
  janitor::clean_names()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a    x1    x5
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4    10
#> 2     2     5    11
#> 3     3     6    12
```

It seems like the naming setup in `readxl` is a topic of debate: see [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/548) issue, among others on the best way to convert unusable names from Excel sheets. There's also a [vignette](https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/column-names.html) on it. To be honest, the last couple times I've needed to mess with `readxl` names, I just passed the data frame to `janitor`.